# map-partition with extra parameters pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark

I want to pass few extra parameters to the python function from the mappartition. Any suggestions..

My sample code looks like this

```
 def test(x,abc):
   <<code>>

 abc =1234
 df = df.repartition("key")
 res= df.rdd.mapPartitions(test, abc)
```

If i pass abc as parameter and use it inside the test funtion i am getting below error

Exception: It appears that you are attempting to broadcast an RDD or reference an RDD from an action or transformation. RDD transformations and actions can only be invoked by the driver, not inside of other transformations; for example, rdd1.map(lambda x: rdd2.values.count() * x) is invalid because the values transformation and count action cannot be performed inside of the rdd1.map transformation. For more information, see SPARK-5063.

Mariusz please find the change

```
from pyspark.sql import Row
def test(abc):
    def my_map_partitions(x):
       print("----------start-----------")
       cnt=1
       ret = []
       for i in x:
         cnt=cnt+1
         val = Row(key1=i.key1, key2=i.key2, cnt=cnt)
         ret.append(val)
       return ret 
    return my_map_partitions
df = df.repartition("key1key2").sortWithinPartitions("key1key2")  
abc123 = df .rdd.mapPartitions(test(abc))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try creating function that returns function, for example:

```
def test(abc):
    def my_map_partitions(partition):
        ...do something with partition and abc...
    return my_map_partitions

df.rdd.mapPartitions(test(abc))
```

Comment: I am getting this error .TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

Comment: In what function. Does your my_map_partitions return iterable variable (like a list?)

Comment: Mariusz .. i have added code in original post.. for each partition i will convert list of rows to list of list and apply julia lme then return the list of rows back to caller

Comment: There is missing `return my_map_partitions` in your code. Function test is used to "generate" my_map_partitions function so it needs to return it.

Comment: Thank Mariusz .. that worked. But i see lot of empty partitions, how can we get ride of it. Do you want me to check length of list and ignore empty? or any other solution?

Comment: After `mapPartitions` you will have as many partitions as before running this transformation, because it maps old partition to the new partition. To get rid of empty partitions run `.coalesce(1)` at the end.

Comment: When you say at the end is it after repartition i have to coalesce? I dont want to call python function for empty partitions. Is there any way to filter that before i  call `df.rdd.mapPartitions(test(abc))`

Comment: I didn't notice repartition before mapPartitions. Are you sure you have empty partitions after repartitioning by column? Partitioning will be the same after calling mapPartitions

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128480/discussion-between-harish-and-mariusz).